# AngularJS Binding: Dropdown binds string, need number instead

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a dropdown that allows the user to select a number.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedNum" ng-change="numberSelected()">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Back in my controller, I can reference the selected value via $scope.selectedNumber

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedNum = 10;

    $scope.numberSelected = function(){
        alert(typeof $scope.selectedNum); //alerts string, need this to be a number
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96qDy/1/)

I'm new to angular - coming from jQuery I'm used to explicitly invoking Number($('#mySelect').val()) but in angular the value is bound automatically to the $scope.

My question: is there a way to force $scope.selectedNum to be type number? In my actual project I use the selectedNum to do some calculations. I suppose I can use Number(..) or parseInt(..) in various places but I'm thinking that might get a little repetitive and messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that te **option value** is a **CDATA** in HTML - so it is a **string** in your code. You may solve your problem if you are using an **array of numbers** and the **ng-options** directive:

in you controller you may add:

```
$scope.nums = [10,20,30,40,50];
```

and in your view:

```
<select 
      ng-model="selectedNum" 
      ng-change="numberSelected()" 
      ng-options="n for n in nums">
</select>
```

now you will got a number in your controller function:

```
$scope.numberSelected = function(){
   console.log(typeof $scope.selectedNum,    $scope.selectedNum);
}
```

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5aHRL/

Comment: Good explanation, thanks! I had a feeling that using the ng-options directive would solve it.